# Is there any relation between n(A)and n(B)under following condition

Tags: functions, relations, cross-product, coprime

$A=\{1,2,3,4,.....,n\}$, $n(A)=n$,
$B=\{(x,y)| x \text{ and } y \text{ are co-prime }, x,y \in A\}$
,$B \subseteq A \times A$.
Is there any relation between $n(A)$ and $n(B)$?
If yes what is the relation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Euler's Totient function, $n(B)$ is just $$2\sum_1^{n(A)}\phi(k)-1.$$

I don't believe there is any neater form than this.